# Add a datepicker to a cell but only with months in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, datepicker, google-sheets-formula

How can I add a datepicker to a cell just with the months? I dont need the days.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use [Data Validation](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/186103?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en) and pick from a list.

You can enter the list in the Data Validation prompt or perhaps you would make a list elsewhere and reference it. You were not clear on if you wanted just months or months + years, although this solution would still be valid, just what goes into your list.

[image]

[image]

### Reference

- [Create an in-cell dropdown list](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/186103?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en)

Answer (score 0):

Data Validation is the way to go. Just use "List of items" > the months separated by commas instead of "List from a range"

[image: 1]